# Git branch merged to master causes "No Known Class Method for Selector" errors in Xcode project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git

I'm working on an iOS app and the first release of it went onto the app store last week, I've had some ideas on things to add to it and some things I want to change based on user feedback. I decided to do feature branches for every major new section. I completed the first feature branch and verified the app works properly without any warnings or errors.

I merged the branch into master without any conflicts, after opening the successfully merged master in Xcode and attempting to run it I'm receiving a lot of "No known class method for selector", "Duplicate interface definition for class", and "Property has a previous declaration" errors. I've looked through all of the files it mentions and they all are exactly as they were in the feature branch. The biggest problem causing files are the Reachability one's from Apple.

Here's an example of one of the files throwing "No known class method for selector". It's doing it for the `create`, `update`, and `remove` methods. All of these methods were added in the feature branch.

The .h file:

```
//
//  Services.h
//  MovieQueue
//
//  Created by Joshua Kendall on 2/22/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Simple App Group LLC. All rights reserved.
//

@interface Services : NSObject

+ (NSArray *)search:(NSString *)movieTitle;
+ (NSDictionary *)getMovieDetails:(NSInteger)movieId;

+ (void)create:(NSDictionary *)record;
+ (void)update:(NSDictionary *)record;
+ (void)remove:(id)movieId;

@end
```

And the redacted .m file:

```
//
//  Services.m
//  MovieQueue
//
//  Created by Joshua Kendall on 2/22/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Simple App Group LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Services.h"

@implementation Services

#pragma mark - API Access

+ (NSArray *)search:(NSString *)movieTitle {
...
}

+ (NSDictionary *)getMovieDetails:(NSInteger)movieId {
...
}

#pragma mark - CRUD

+ (void)create:(NSDictionary *)record {
...
}

+ (void)update:(NSDictionary *)record {
...
}

+ (void)remove:(id)movieId {
...
}

@end
```

Comment: It's nice that you've given us some code, but unfortunately it's irrelevant.  Give us an example of a line that's causing you problems.

Comment: The line's causing the problems are `[Services create:item]`, `[Services update:item]`, and `[Services remove:item]`. Regardless of where they are called its throwing a "No known class method for selector". The Services header is being loaded in the app's .pch file.  The methods are clearly defined in both the header and implementation files. I don't believe it's an issue with the code, but an issue caused by branch merging with Git.

Comment: Diff the project and see what's changed then.  I'll bet you're missing some import statements, but you might be right about git being the problem.  Xcode and git are... Not the most compatible entities

Comment: Ok, I went through and it was an issue with imports. I was using the .pch file to import the Services header file, once I removed it from there and placed it in the headers for the classes that call it's methods it solved the issues. I was under the impression that the .pch file was a good place to put imports that are used by the entire project, but apparently that's not a good thing to do. This [link](http://qualitycoding.org/precompiled-headers/) explained the problems with it.

Comment: Just do you know, it is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out this was an issue with imports, I had all of my common files like the Services class imported in the application's .PCH file. I've done this in all of the app's I've ever built because it made more sense than importing the same file in every view controller.

I took [CodaFi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/945847/codafi)'s suggestion and checked imports, after importing the services header into one of the classes that was having an issue build without issue I started looking at the .PCH file since it seemed to be the cause.

It turns out that the .PCH file is not a replacement for importing the file in each class that uses it. They have to still be imported into each class. This page "[4 Ways Precompiled Headers Cripple Your Code](http://qualitycoding.org/precompiled-headers/)" explained the issue to me specifically the section entitled "Find and fix the missing #imports".

I'm guessing I've never had an issue with it before this because I've never used branches for an iOS project before.